# Composer install error when trying to install php phantom js on laravel 5.1 mac

Tags: installation, phantomjs, laravel-5.1

Im trying to install *php phantom js* on *laravel 5.1*, but keep getting a weird error:

> "Class PhantomInstaller\Installer is not autoloadable, can not call
>   post-install-cmd script"

I have written the following to my composer.json file, added a bin folder to my root and then run composer install, to no avail:

```
"require": {
        "jonnyw/php-phantomjs": "3.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "PhantomInstaller\\Installer::installPhantomJS"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "PhantomInstaller\\Installer::installPhantomJS"
        ]
    }
```

Does anybody have any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Fixed:  I ran composer dump-autoload then ran composer UPDATE.  This seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error, fixed by installing the `@dev` version.

Here is my `composer.json`, it works fine.

```
{
  "type": "project",
  "license": "proprietary",
  "require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "ext-ctype": "*",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "google/apiclient": "^2.2",
    "jonnyw/php-phantomjs": "@dev",
    "keboola/csv": "^2.0",
    "rtheunissen/guzzle-log-middleware": "^0.4.1",
    "secit-pl/imap-bundle": "^1.3",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.2",
    "smalot/pdfparser": "^0.13.2",
    "symfony/cache": "*",
    "symfony/console": "*",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.1",
    "jakoch/phantomjs-installer": "2.1.1-p09",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "*",
    "symfony/yaml": "*"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "neronmoon/scriptsdev": "dev-master",
    "symfony/dotenv": "*"
  },
  "config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin",
    "preferred-install": {
      "*": "dist"
    },
    "sort-packages": true
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "src/"
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
  },
  "replace": {
    "paragonie/random_compat": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "auto-scripts": {
      "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
      "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
    },
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "@auto-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "@auto-scripts"
    ]
  },
  "conflict": {
    "symfony/symfony": "*"
  },

  "extra": {
    "scripts-dev": {
      "post-install-cmd": [
        "PhantomInstaller\\Installer::installPhantomJS"
      ],
      "post-update-cmd": [
        "PhantomInstaller\\Installer::installPhantomJS"
      ]
    },
    "symfony": {
      "require": "4.1.*"
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this will help to solve the problem.